# C++ socket server to Flash/Adobe AIR?

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, air, augmented-reality, socketserver

I am using AIR to do some augmented reality using fudicial marker tracking. I am using FLARToolkit and it works fine, except the frame rate drops to ridiculous lows in certain lighting conditions. This is because Flash only uses the CPU for processing, and every frame it is applying filters, adjusting thresholds, and analyzing the pixels to find the marker pattern. Without any hardware acceleration, it can get really slow.

I did some searching and it looks like the fastest and most stable tracking library is Studierstube ( http://handheldar.icg.tugraz.at/stbtracker.php and http://studierstube.icg.tugraz.at/download.php ). Unfortunately, I am not a C++ developer. But it seems that the tracking is insanely fast using this tracker (especially since it isn't all CPU processing like Flash is).

So my plan is to build (or rather have someone build) a small C++ program that leverages this tracker, and then sends the marker position data every frame (only need 30 FPS) to my Flash client application to display back the video and some augmented reality experiences. I believe this would be done through a socket server or something right? Is this possible and fairly easy for someone who is a decent C++ developer? I would ask him/her but I am in search for such a person.

Comment: Have you looked at native extensions?  Basically you can compile your c++ into a dll that you can call from flash -- you can spawn new threads, etc etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

May this link will be helpful?

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html

As some told here, it'll be done with nativeprocess...